# How to get the latest browser version of Google Chrome to update my user-agent?

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to get the latest version with python2.7 of Google Chrome to use it in my user-agent. Is there a fast way to achieve this?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here ?

Comment: I need the most recent browser version of Chrome for a script that I'm running in python. Example: "Mozilla/x.x ... AppleWebKit/xxx.xx ... Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/xxx.xx". So I can check incomming headers for outdated browsers and to use it so I don't have one myself when sending requests with a predetermined header.

Comment: Not sure if there is some API to return only the "latest chrome user agent string", but you can try scraping https://www.whatismybrowser.com/guides/the-latest-user-agent/chrome to get the latest google chrome user agent, and then use it in your script.